# Get data with React Redux Call Axios many time but can not render data till I refresh it

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, react-redux

I am create website with React Redux using axios to get data API, but when I want to render it to my page, it can not read till I refresh the page by hot reload or saving project again. Here is my code:

Screen:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MNom.png)

Controller: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAmUk.png)

I test in inspect got data but the page still does not show anything till I hot reload it.

Page: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONs4n.png)

Is it because I called axios in axios or my UseState is wrong. Thanks!